# Как включить дискорд бота на Python на сервере

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Бот работает в личных сообщениях, но не работает на сервере. Разрешение на отправку сообщений включены, на сервере бот авторизован, роль выше всех, но он всё равно на сервере не работает. Иногда только ошибка вылетает:Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected. Или наоборот, когда что-то дополнительное из intents добавляю, пишет, что разрешения нужно подключить в ds dev portal, но они уже подключены

```
`import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.dm_messages = True
intents.moderation = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)


@bot.command(name='commands')
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete()
    await ctx.send('Кое-что')

@bot.command(name='Кое-что')
async def Кое-что(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Кое-что')

@bot.command(name='Кое-что')
async def Кое-что(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Кое-что')

bot.run('Токен')`
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в портал разработчика discord: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Выберете своего бота и зайдите в раздел **Bot**.

Поставьте галочку на **MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]